# Android sub-library not in build path

Tags: java, android, jar, libraries, noclassdeffounderror

I'm currently making an App which uses a library (Let's call it parentLib) that I have made. This library also uses another library I have made (Let's call it childLib). So the top app is including a .jar file (parentLib), and in that .jar file is another .jar file (childLib).

The problem though, is that when I come to use an aspect of the sub-library (childLib) from the top level app, I get a NoClassDefFoundError message, which crashes the app.

The weird thing is, if I add the sub-library (childLib) into the App's libs folder alongside the library (parentLib) directly, then things work, even though it's not actually using those library files. It seems as if it just needs the sub-library (childLib) adding to the build path of the library (parentLib) so that the app knows where to look for it, but I'm really not sure?

The sub-library (childLib) works perfectly when used directly form the initial App, but I need to be able to distribute the sub-library (childLib) as part of a single file (parentLib.jar) which includes it.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your Java build path for the project library exporting Android dependencies? In Eclipse, you can check this under that project's properties, under "Java Build Path", under the "Order and Export" tab.

Comment: Yep, it is exporting both Private Dependencies and Android Dependencies, as well as its own /src and /gen directories (I have tried having them in reverse order as per another answer to a similar question.

Comment: Does the jar in question appear in the list of Android private libraries? In Eclipse, you can check this under that project's properties, under "Java Build Path", under the "Libraries" tab; expand the "Android Private Libraries" entry to view all jars.

Comment: And the follow-up question: does the jar also appear in the private libraries of the application project?

Comment: The parentLib's .jar includes childLib.jar in its Private Libraries. The application includes parentLib.jar in its Private Libraries but not childLib.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the problem, as I believed the parent to be a project library. Android is only clever enough to sort out nested dependencies if the parent is an Android project in itself. Simply including a jar within a jar won't work, because the build path entries can't be resolved. I'm not sure if there's a way to provide this manually, but certainly the easiest and most portable fix is to either ensure that the parent is either an AAR (Android Studio only) or an Android project that's set up as a library, or simply include the nested jar separately in your child project.

Comment: Hmmm, sadly using an Android project library exposes more of the source code than I would like to have to do. This is very disappointing news :( Thank you for your help, do you have a link to any documentation on this?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't have any reference docs; this is purely from my experience. I've never tried this, but perhaps you can merge the contents of the nested jar into the parent jar using an archiving program?

Comment: Sadly the nested jar is quite bulky, and there are actually 7 or 8 different nested jars I would have to merge in, making the currently slimline parentLib very very large :(

Comment: Your best long-term strategy would definitely be migrating to Gradle. For now, I'm afraid you're stuck with providing the parent jar and all referenced jars with it... and a manual.

Comment: Does Gradle definitively solve this problem then? And would I be able to use Android Studio to produce the finalised parentLib (Containing the childLib) and then use that library with Eclipse do you think?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain about that as I'm not very nimble with Gradle myself, but I'm confident you'd have much better control over which dependencies your library depends on. I'm afraid you'd have to consult with somebody else to get a concrete answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help Paul, I have opened up a new question with what I think is a more informed explanation. Should this yield a different answer I will post it here.

Unfortunately after trying Android Studio, I found it to cause the same NoClassDefError that I received with Eclipse, despite creating the libraries and main App again in that from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by moving to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

> ...I need to be able to distribute the sub-library (childLib) as part of a single file (parentLib.jar) which includes it.

You could "merge" the `parentLib` and the `childLib` under the same package (I mean "merge" their source folders) and only then create the jar for distribution.

Comment: Merging is possible, but would somewhat complicate matters. As parentLib.jar will always be distributed, but childLib will only sometimes be distributed. The functionality to allow this is for a later date mind you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, in android, inside a project '**A**', you can only refer a class '**b**' from the library '**B**', if and only if '**B**' is directly added to '**A**' , as library or project reference. Either make the two libraries to One or add both to main project.

Comment: Do you have any source on this? As if this is the definitive "rule" then it is very damaging to the intended outcome here :(

Comment: I had a similar issue which is also related to cyclic dependency.. I tried to access the files from my parent project and in my case it was not working. i believe, i am not sure.. my question is in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803409/how-to-overcome-cyclic-reference-error-in-android